# Regular expression involving word boundaries to extract between open tag and end tag gives unexpected results

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to write some tcl code that will exact the everything between and opening tag and a closing tag, and put each occurance as an entry into an array.

My begin tag is `module`, and my end tag is `endmodule`. I put `\b` around it so it only matches the boundary. And I'm using `.*?` so that its a non-greedy match.

An example string `verilog_string` is:

```
set verilog_string {
    module first_module;
        // Verilog code
        //jhkjhkh
    endmodule
    
    non-module code
    123
    456...
    
    module second_module;
       //code2
       //lkjkjljk
       //jkjhkhjkjhkh
    endmodule
}
```

Array position 1 should contain:

```
module first_module;
    // Verilog code
    //jhkjhkh
endmodule
```

Array position 2 should contain:

```
module second_module;
   //code2
   //lkjkjljk
   //jkjhkhjkjhkh
endmodule
```

Here's what I have so far:

##### Attempt 1

```
proc extract_verilog_modules {verilog_string} {
    set content $verilog_string
    set modules_list {}
    

    # Match 'module' to 'endmodule' including multiline matches
    set module_pattern {\bmodule\b.*?\bendmodule\b}

    foreach module [regexp -all -inline $module_pattern $content] {
        puts "here"
        lappend modules_list $module
    }

    return $modules_list
}

set extracted_modules [extract_verilog_modules $verilog_string]

puts "here 1"
foreach module $extracted_modules {
    puts "Extracted Module:\n$module"
}
puts "here 2"
```

##### Attempt 2

```
proc extract_verilog_modules {verilog_string} {
    set content $verilog_string
    set modules_list {}
    
    set module_pattern {(?m)^\s*module\b.*?(?:(?=\n\s*endmodule\b)|(?=endmodule\b))}
    set endmodule_pattern {endmodule\b}

    foreach module_match [regexp -all -inline -- $module_pattern $content] {
        set line_number [lsearch -inline -regexp [split $content "\n"] [string trimleft $module_match]]
        set char_position [string first $module_match $line_number]
        
        set module_content ""
        set in_module 1
        foreach line [split $module_match "\n"] {
            if {$in_module} {
                append module_content "$line\n"
            }
            if {[regexp $endmodule_pattern $line]} {
                set in_module 0
            }
        }
        lappend modules_list [list $module_content $line_number $char_position]
    }
    
    return $modules_list
}
```

##### Attempt 3

```
proc extract_verilog_modules {verilog_string} {
    set content [string map {"\t" "    "} $verilog_string]
    set content [regsub -all {(?:\r?\n|\n\r)} $content "\t"]

    set modules_list {}

    set module_pattern {\s*module\b}
    set endmodule_pattern {endmodule\b}

    set module_index 0
    set endmodule_index 0

    while {[regexp -start $module_index -- $module_pattern $content -> module_start]} {
        set module_end [expr {$module_start + $module_index + [string length "module"]}]
        set module_index [expr {$module_end}]

        if {[regexp -start $endmodule_index -- $endmodule_pattern $content -> endmodule_start]} {
            set endmodule_end [expr {$endmodule_start + $endmodule_index + [string length "endmodule"]}]
            set endmodule_index [expr {$endmodule_end}]

            set module_content [string range $content $module_start $endmodule_end]
            set module_content [string map {"\t" "\n"} $module_content]

            set original_content [string map {"\t" "\n"} $content]
            set lines [split $original_content "\n"]
            set line_number 1
            foreach line $lines {
                if {[string first $module_content $line] >= 0} {
                    break
                }
                incr line_number
            }
            set char_position [string first $module_content $line]

            lappend modules_list [list $module_content $line_number $char_position]
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    if {[llength $modules_list] == 0} {
        puts "No matches found for the regex pattern."
    }

    return $modules_list
}
```

But I get no output.

Comment: What problem do you have ?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not get the output "here 1"?

Comment: Try [`(?n)^[\t ]*module.*(?:\n(?![\t ]*endmodule).*)*\n[\t ]*endmodule`](https://tio.run/##dVJNb4MwDL3zKzyG1BapoHYfh@3Q04697tJ2CIFbPtKAgpkqIX47C0lKKduiSCjP9vPzMxSxrrMqJPhGkbLiFFQkUn6CxgJ5zkVcM4RjKioK9ONdBfrj@/CpiyAqYhzhWZLLmygEeawLLfXkBV8a1qFotX5S3@eXV8/zrHHnCqOCx9PWvt/Xrm9Plmd5xrL8hmRKQfaXjtaySlFEgBcSYUTBdXIdrqC5t6I1XvQmSTGEnMC5TxnihiJgaUXQtArX8zzCNqQogZlOmQEVMBs0zSDlEavj3vlzzShlKUc49xVYTdiDMiRCwaGZb/jia7cnOLg65LnzzduezzcPGh34F567cPd8grZa2rEQGEppxvKdwBNeSliGjMEy5UqKM@ntGCcOxpz@lDVVYCco0B4wFpal7HdvjCFTSUaDQKp72nFevyj1a5pFYTysaPff7iaLOchVD6pgZVuTWZ3f1HoeXfVxjcJWRaW3RqEtxY2Y17bVdT8)

Answer (score 3):

As [documented](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.html), in Tcl regexps, `\b` matches a backspace character (ASCII 0x7F). Word boundaries are matched by `\y` (or `\m` or `\M` if you want to be specific about which end of the word; not usually necessary).

---

[EDIT]: With your samples, I get the right thing with:

```
set modules [regexp -all -inline {\ymodule\s+?\w+;.*\yendmodule\y} $verilog_string]
```

We need a more complex RE because a module only really starts if it is followed by a module name (matched by `\w+`) and a semicolon. Without that, we get confused by `non-module`.

The `?` in there is *critical* and must be placed on the *first quantifier* (or all of them) to select non-greediness for the whole RE. (I can only sort of explain this one; greediness affects which sort of automata the RE is compiled to, and that decision is taken at the first quantifier, but the RE compiler has some odd ideas about what is first. In reality, I just tested this until it worked!)

I've assumed no comment format needs to be paid attention to. If the comment format matters, the RE gets quite a bit longer and the matching more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I found that ActiveState TCL doesn't support \b for wordboundries. I had to use an older syntax:  [[:<:]]module[[:>:]]

```
proc extract_verilog_modules {verilog_string} {
    set content $verilog_string
    set modules_list {}
    

    # Match 'module' to 'endmodule' including multiline matches
    set module_pattern {\bmodule\b.*?\bendmodule\b}

    set bundle []
    foreach item $bundle {
        puts "match: $item"
    }

    foreach module [regexp -inline -all {[[:<:]]module[[:>:]](?=\s).*?[[:<:]]endmodule[[:>:]]} $content] {
        lappend modules_list $module
    }

    return $modules_list
}

set extracted_modules [extract_verilog_modules $verilog_string2]

foreach module $extracted_modules {
    puts "Extracted Module:\n$module"
}
```

Comment: What's your Tcl version? `puts [info patchlevel]`